# Can I use a 3 speed wall switch with a ceiling fan that comes with a remote?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, home-automation

I'm not too familiar with fan motors/configurations. I'd like to install a fan and use a [Z Wave 3 speed switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XTKQTTV) to control the fan speed, and a [Z Wave dimmer switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006LQFHN2) to control the lighting in the fan. The Z Wave component shouldn't matter. I'd like to use a 3 speed switch to control fan speed and a dimmer to control the light in the fan.

In my mind, there are two different types of fans: 1) controlled by a remote (comes with or works with the fan/light combo) and 2) pull strings on fan/light combo.

Questions:

1. Is it correct to assume that I cannot use a 3 speed wall switch with a fan that comes with its own remote?
2. Is it correct to assume that I can use a 3 speed wall switch with a fan that has a pull string to change the speed of the fan?

Or better yet, what type of fan can use that will be compatible with the above referenced 3 speed switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get a fan that does *not* have a built-in remote receiver

Most fans with built-in receivers have the remote receiver rather tightly coupled to the fan, with no instructions for how to remove it and all power to the receiver for both fan and light control supplied by a single hot wire.  Fans with pull-chains, though, do not have this problem -- their fan and light hot wires are brought out separately, allowing use with whatever setup you wish, whether it be a "quiet 3 speed" control or a fully variable control, as well as multi-way setups.